# Google-api-client for Multipart POST request

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client

I use google-api-client for android. I try to do multipart POST request with text data and image file. Code snippet for creating request is below:

```cs
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(fileToSend);
InputStreamContent photoContent = new InputStreamContent("image/jpeg", stream);
MultipartRelatedContent multiContent =
    new MultipartRelatedContent(content, photoContent); 
HttpRequest request = getRequestFactory().buildPostRequest(googleUrl, multiContent);
```

content is key-value text content. As a result I get error 500.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a guide here about how to do media upload with the google-api-java-client here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/MediaUpload

That said, I don't anything necessarily wrong with your code either.  It is possible that the googleUrl is incorrect, or that content is not properly formatted.  You might want to try adding a URL query parameter uploadType=multipart to specify that you are using multipart as the protocol.